# How to open cmd.exe on server through local machine using batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file

Hi friends I want to open cmd on server.I have a java code on my local machine that run a batch file(Run.bat) on server the code runs successfully but does't open a cmd.exe on server, but whenever I go to server and double click on my batch file on server it's open a cmd.

Thanks in advance.

java code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c",
                    "F:\\Softwares\\PsTool\\PsExec.exe \\\\aa.aa.aa.aa -u Administrator -p 1234 \"c:\\batch\\Run.bat\"");


            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = builder.start();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while (true) {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Run.bat:

```
start cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. As the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) state:

> By default, the subprocess writes standard output and standard error to pipes. Java code can access these pipes via the input streams returned by Process.getInputStream() and Process.getErrorStream(). However, standard output and standard error may be redirected to other destinations using redirectOutput and redirectError.

Simplified: the `ProcessBuilder` doesn't generate any Console-Windows, but instead simply redirects output from any command to a pipe that can be read from the javaapp.

Comment: Dear Paul can U plz suggest me in clear words what i have to do in this matter?

Comment: @Bilbo There isn't much to suggest, the console-window won't appear (or atleast i haven't found any way of getting it to appear in quite some years). So there isn't much to suggest except for simply using `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()` to redirect the streams to the Out-/Input of the console of the java-app and use these streams as replacement for the console.